# IE 10, Edge box-shadow not working

Tags: html, box-shadow

My problem is:
I make a website, and I have a `<p>` tag with text. The text in this row will wrap, and need to be shadow on this "box". It works in Google Chrome,Mozilla and Safari, but in IE not working.[There are solid lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wrlh.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: add  your code, so that it will be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this as follows:
The only reason it might not be working is if the browser is rendering the page using Quirks mode or Compatibility mode. Either of these modes will disable the feature, because they're designed to emulate older versions of IE which did not have it.

To check if you're in one of these modes, press F12 to bring up the Dev tools window. In IE10, the mode information should be displayed at the top of the window. If it says anything other than "Browser Mode: IE10" and "Document Mode: Standards", then you've found the cause of the problem.
Add a valid doctype to the top of your code, above the  tag as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Add the X-UA-Compatible meta tag somewhere inside your HTML  element, as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This should make sure IE10 loads the page in standards mode, which should in turn sort out the problems with the